# Problem with Double and BigDecimal property created in Hana from Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hana

We noticed that every BigDecimal and Double properties created in Hybris, are created in Hana as  decimal(30,8). When we try to save the value 0 to these properties in Hybris, they are saved in Hana as "-0.00000256", See attached Image:

[image]

Is there some work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the jdbc driver version being used is supported for the HANA revision, this issue can be caused by unsupported client being used.